# How to solve this: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-custom-view, android-dialog

I have been found in StackOverFlow about this problem many times,but I can't find the  problem similar to mine.So I have to ask this question.

**I have a custom button in viewpager,when I press this button,a dialog will show.**

But It always crashed because **Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application**

Can anyone help me solve this problem,thanks a lot!

Below is the custom button:

```
public class RecordButton extends CircleButton {
 ....
 private Dialog recordIndicator;
 private void initDialogStartRecord() {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    recordIndicator = new Dialog(context,
            R.style.like_toast_dialog_style);
    recordIndicator.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
    imageView.setImageResource(res[0]);
    recordIndicator.setContentView(
            imageView,
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    recordIndicator.setOnDismissListener(onDismiss);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = recordIndicator.getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    startRecording();
    recordIndicator.show();
}
```

And this is the viewpager:

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_photoword,
            container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.iv_photoword);
    Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtil.decodeBitmapFromFile(pathList.get(position), AppConstant.SCREEN_WIDTH, 50);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)
    RecordButton button = (RecordButton) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.bt_record);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    FileUtil.getFileFolder("/Myapp/Record/");
    String path = "/Myapp/Record/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".amr";
    System.out.println("path------>" + path);
    button.setSavePath(path);
    button.setOnFinishedRecordListener(new RecordButton.OnFinishedRecordListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFinishedRecord(String audioPath) {
            System.out.println("audiopath:---->" + audioPath);
        }
    });
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout, 0);
    return viewLayout;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of creating **Dialog** and **ImageView** you have to pass **Activity** reference not **Context**

So change following lines if you are doing in **Activity**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
imageView = new ImageView(this);
```

(OR)

if you are doing in **Fragment**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: But I am doing in ViewPagerAdapter.What about that?

Comment: @JohnnyTsai Take a parametrized constructor in ViewPagerAdapter and pass Activity reference at the time of creating ViewPagerAdapter and use it where ever you want in ViewPagerAdapter.

Comment: Sorry! I created a dialog in custom button not in viewpager.In fact,I uesd this custom button in viewpager.When I click this button,a dialog will show.And a image which indicate the change of volume will show in dialog .I donnot know how to pass the activity reference to custom button.So I did this: Activity activity = (Activity)Context.But it didn't work.

Comment: @JohnnyTsai Then pass Activity reference from viewpager to RecordButton.

Comment: Can you tell me how to pass? As you know,Custom View redefine three methods,But how I can I pass reference to RecordButton? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnnyTsai take parameterized constructor in RecordButton and pass Activity reference in ViewPagerAdapter while creating RecordButton object.

Comment: I create RecordButton in XML file,and I just declared that in ViewPagerAdapter.So how can I pass while I did this:RecordButton button = (RecordButton)viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.bt_record);

Comment: @JohnnyTsai Then write initDialogStartRecord() in viewpager itself and call in onClick(-).

Answer (score 0):

This is `context` problem. Here, what is 'getContext()` in

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder.(getContext());
```

Use Activity context. That will solve your problem, pass `context` from your activity to that custom button while calling custom button, then use that `context` to create `Dialog`.

Comment: But what I used is Dialog,not **AlterDiolog**

Comment: above code i was copied from your only... check once.. and then show full code. to resolve you r problem.

Comment: I have my ApplicationContext passed into my Adapter's constructor but I still get the error.